# How to improve Azure virtual network performances?

Tags: java, azure, nginx, virtual-network

I created a Virtual Network on azure and I am facing a lot of performance issues (10 sec to get ssh channel, 26 sec for ajax query witch takes 10ms). I can't find any information about it on google but I can't imagine the service would still be used if it couldn't be enhanced.

The backend servers are Linux CentOS servers (nginx and java app server).

Thanks for sharing your tip and advises.

(I am also using webSockets but I don't feel like it's related with my problem)

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of delays are usually DNS related. The server tries to perform a reverse DNS but cannot access a DNS service due to its configuration or its firewall. Eventually it times out and sends the document anyway.

Comment: Yes It was an aspect of the  issue  and  it was due to azure service migration.